# Xcode distributing IOS app as other items

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I am trying to Archive my react native iOS app and upload it to app store, but in organizer window it shows Distribute content instead of upload to App Store

[image: Distribute button shown on right side of screen]

[image: Edit scheme window]

Comment: Make sure you're archiving the right target

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right thing? https://i.postimg.cc/ZY3ddBYH/111.png

Comment: anyone please!?

Comment: Please [edit] to provide more information, instead of hiding it in comments.

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't have enough reputation to insert photos other than links, if you have a help please help

Comment: After asking your question in an answer you fixed by making an actual question. Now you have answered your own question with something that is not an answer again. Please take the [tour], read [ask], https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ 
 https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ These links disclose the secrets of writing good questions. Please compare their recomendations to your one sentence two picture version of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a change in the button title in XCode. Mine says 'Distribute App' instead of 'Upload' now. Seems to work exactly the same.

Comment: it is not, it is showing for me Distribute Content which is not an app !

Comment: In Organizer>Archives it should show the App icon and name. If it shows anything else, check the target and device (Generic iOS Device) on the XCode toolbar when you archive.

Comment: it is all ok I am Archiving the target app and selecting Generic IOS app, but in Archive it is not showing the app icon and name !!